# How to save list of object wuth ASW Amplify api with flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

i am trying to learn aws amplify for flutter i have followed the tutorial on how to save a TODO which is simple they have another model  which is this

```
type Blog @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  posts: [Post] @hasMany
}

type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  blog: Blog @belongsTo
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  post: Post @belongsTo
  content: String!
}
```

i use it like this

```
  Future<void> createBlog() async {
    try {
      final blog = Blog(name: 'dummy Blog', posts: [
        Post(title: 'dummy title', comments: [
          Comment(content: 'Comment 1'),
          Comment(content: 'Comment 2'),
          Comment(content: 'Comment 3')
        ])
      ]);
      final request = ModelMutations.create(blog);
      final response = await Amplify.API.mutate(request: request).response;

      final createdBlog = response.data;
      if (createdBlog == null) {
        safePrint('errors: ${response.errors}');
        return;
      }
      safePrint(
          'Mutation result: ${createdBlog.posts?.first.comments?.first.content}');
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      safePrint('Mutation failed: $e');
    }
  }
```

when i call createBlog in the safe print i get "Mutation result null"

in the backend i can see the blog created but the comments and Post are not, not sure what im doing wrong